# get highest value with query result in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query that results column

```
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|  id  | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|   1  | John | 2007-01-24 |        250         |
|   2  | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |        220         |
|   3  | Jack | 2007-05-06 |        170         |
|   3  | Jack | 2007-04-06 |        100         |
|   4  | Jill | 2007-04-06 |        220         |
|   5  | Zara | 2007-06-06 |        300         |
|   5  | Zara | 2007-02-06 |        350         |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

I want max value of this result in another column my output be like

```
+------+------+------------+--------------------+-----------+
|  id  | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages | Max  daily|
+------+------+------------+--------------------+-----------+
|   1  | John | 2007-01-24 |        250         | 350       |
|   2  | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |        220         | 350       |
|   3  | Jack | 2007-05-06 |        170         | 350       |
|   3  | Jack | 2007-04-06 |        100         | 350       |
|   4  | Jill | 2007-04-06 |        220         | 350       |
|   5  | Zara | 2007-06-06 |        300         | 350       |
|   5  | Zara | 2007-02-06 |        350         | 350       |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: You can use a `CROSS JOIN` with a derived table that returns the max value. If you show us the structure of your tables we might be able to provide a concrete query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @maxValue = (select max(daily_typing_pages) from your_table); 
select *, @maxValue from your_table
```

Using this you do not have to use join condition.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the max of the `daily_typing_pages` field in a subquery and join it as a derived table to your main query without a join condition:

```
select * from yourtable
inner join (select max(daily_typing_pages) as max_daily from yourtable) t
```

The join without a join condition will result in associating each record from both queries with each record from the other table.

Alternatively, use a correlated subquery in the select list if you want to avoid joins:

```
select yourtable.*, (select max(daily_typing_pages) from yourtable) as max_daily from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this query

```
 select *,(select max(daily_typing_pages) from your_table) as max_daily from your_table
```

In this query you can append new column as max_daily whose value is max(daily_typing_pages)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
select *, HighestValue = (select max(TotalAmount) from [dbo].[Order]) from [NorthWindDemo].[dbo].[Order]
```