# While using a SELECT SUM() GROUP BY, how can I still get the individual values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
values = 2,3,4
```

When doing a `JOIN (SELECT *, SUM(values) AS MaxValues FROM table GROUP BY id)`, `$a = $data['MaxValues']` will equal 9 as it should. However, how can I still pull the individual values(2,3,4)? trying a foreach on `$b = $data['values']` only gives me one of the values. I'm assuming because of the required `GROUP BY`. I'm still new  to all of this. Thank you

Comment: two queries, or just run once and iteratively sum the values.

Comment: You can check answers from here as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254226/get-highest-value-with-query-result-in-mysql/44254319#44254319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `group_concat()`, I think:

```
JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(values) AS MaxValues, group_concat(values) as values
      FROM table
      GROUP BY id)
```

Note:  You should not be using `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  Only include the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: group_concat works awesome, Thank you. p.s. I'll fix my * with real column names. Thank you, Thank you, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can select both `values` and `SUM` with `JOIN`. Also, you don't need `GROUP BY` if you want to get all the values, e.g.:

```
SELECT value, a.sum
FROM table, (SELECT SUM(value) AS `sum` FROM table ) a;
```